# credit card number of an unsupported card type issue in commerce_authnet module

Tags: drupal-commerce

We are using `commerce_authnet` module in drupal for processing credit card but it is showing following error for visa & mestro card processing:

"`You have entered a credit card number of an unsupported card type`".

Can anyone tell me how we can remove this issue?

Comment: is it working   on test mode or on live mode   which payment method  you are  useing  direct bank transfer paypal or any other

Comment: It is working on test mode &  we have using commerce_authnet module & It not working for mestro card type.